# google cloud functions with Handlebar templates and nodemailer throws path noth found for views

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I am trying to send custom handlebar templates as email template. The email will be triggered whenever there is an update in a document of a collection.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const hbs = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars');
const options = {
    viewEngine: {
        extname: '.hbs',
        layoutsDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'views/email/'),
        defaultLayout: 'template',
        partialsDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'views/partials/')
    },
    viewPath: 'views/email/',
    extName: '.hbs'
};

const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'test@gmail.com',
        pass: 'testpwd',
    },
});

mailTransport.use("compile", hbs(options));
```

Within the `onUpdate` event of cloud function on a document, I have written below code to send email.

```
mailTransport.sendMail({
            from: "test@site.in",
            to: `toemail`,
            subject: `Test subject`,
            template: "ordermail",
            context: {
                d: mailData
            }
   },
   (error, response) => {
        // console.log("mail sent to " + to);
        console.log("Error", error);
        mailTransport.close();
    }
);
```

My directory structure within functions directory is as below:

```
 -node_modules
 -views
  |_ -email
     |_ordermail.hbs
     |_template.hbs
  |_ -partials
     |_ -email
        |_ -footer.hbs
        |_ -header.hbs
  -index.js
  -package.json
```

But it always throws an error that it's unable to find the view:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/user_code/views/email/ordermail.hbs'

I suspect that `views` directory is not getting uploaded to the server when I deploy functions. How can I make sure that views have been uploaded when I run the command `firebase deploy --only functions` or if its, by default, uploaded to the functions directory, why isn't this able to find the directory? Hope to find some help on this.

**UPDATE**

I can say that `views` directory is getting uploaded when the function is deployed as the file size increases when the `views` directory is included in deployment but am still trying to find the reason for the abovesaid error.

**UPDATE 2** - Turns out that it was just because of spelling mistake with `ordermail` and the template name was `orderemail`. Closing this question accordingly.